# returning paired elements in React JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The Problem:

In React, you want to create a DOM structure by mapping an array, but each item in the array should return 2 elements. e.g.

```
import React from 'react'
import _ from 'lodash'

let { Component } = React

export default class DataList extends Component {
  render () {
    let array = [
      {def: 'item1', term: 'term1', obj1: 'rand'}, 
      {def: 'item2', term: 'term2'}
    ]
    return (
      <dl>
        {_.map(array, (item) => {
          return (
            <dt>{item.def}</dt>
            <dd>{item.term}</dd>
          )
        })}
      </dl>
    )
  }
}
```

React doesn't let you render siblings without wrapping them in a container element, which would break the DOM structure here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could do something simpler with `reduce` like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class DataList extends Component {
  render () {
    const array = [
      {def: 'item1', term: 'term1', obj1: 'rand'}, 
      {def: 'item2', term: 'term2'}
    ];

    return (
      <dl>
        {array.reduce((acc, item, idx) => {
            return acc.concat([
                <dt key={`def-${idx}`}>{item.def}</dt>,
                <dd key={`term-${idx}`}>{item.term}</dd>
            ]);
        }, [])}
      </dl>
    );
  }
}
```

DEMO :: https://jsfiddle.net/rifat/caray95v/

Comment: ha, very nice ... it took a few seconds for me to figure out how it worked, which is the only downside (i.e. slightly less comprehendible from a code readability POV), but a much more elegant solution, and the one I'll be using from now on.

Comment: One more thing: it's generally not recommended that you use the index from the array as the key. Here is a great post on it: https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Comment: [`Fragment`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47793936/2190172) would be the recommended approach to solving this problem now.

Answer (score 10):

React 16.2 added support for [`Fragments`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#keyed-fragments), you can use it like this:

```
return (
  <dl>
    {_.map(array, (item) => {
      return (
        <Fragment>
          <dt>{item.def}</dt>
          <dd>{item.term}</dd>
        </Fragment>
      )
    })}
  </dl>
)
```

You can also use Fragment with empty tag like this:

```
return (
  <dl>
    {_.map(array, (item) => {
      return (
        <>
          <dt>{item.def}</dt>
          <dd>{item.term}</dd>
        </>
      )
    })}
  </dl>
)
```

But keep in mind that if you want to use the `key` attribute on `Fragment` tag you have to use the full version of it. More info on [this](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html) react's blog

Answer (score 0):

I found the simplest way to achieve this is to map over the object keys (lodash supports this) for each item of the array and conditionally render each type of element.

```
import React from 'react'
import _ from 'lodash'

let { Component } = React

export default class DataList extends Component {
  render () {
    let array = [
      {def: 'item1', term: 'term1', obj1: 'rand'}, 
      {def: 'item2', term: 'term2'}
    ]

    return (
      <dl>
        {_.map(array, (item) => {
          return _.map(item, (elem, key) => {
            if (key === 'def') {
              return <dt>{elem}</dt>
            } else if (key === 'term') {
              return <dd>{elem}</dd>
            }
          })
        })}
      </dl>
    )
  }
}
```