# Having problem in putting headings in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to put h1 heading, but if I put the only heading and comment out buttons then heading doesn't print. And if I comment heading then the buttons does not print. But together doesn't print anything. Any suggestion?

### React:

```
class App extends React.Component {  
  constructor(props) {  
    super(props);
      this.state = {    
         drumPads : [   
          {  
            id: "Q",  
            src: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3",
            beat: "Heater-1",
          },
          {
            id: "W",
            src: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-2.mp3",
            beat: "Heater-2"
          },
    }     

 handleClick(id, beat) {
     return () => {
        document.getElementById(id).play();
        this.setState({
          beatName: beat,
         });
     };
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <Fragment>
           <h1>DrumMachine</h1>
           <div>
              this.state.drumPads.map((button, i) =>
                   <button key={i}  onClick={this.handleClick(button.id, button.beat)}><h1>{ button.id }</h1>
                       <audio id={button.id} src={button.src} />
                   </button>
              )
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    )
   }
  }

  ReactDOM.render( <App />,
     document.getElementById("root")
   )
```

Comment: I have edited the code and added Fragment, but still is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a single parent element as opposed to `<div></div>` followed by another `<div></div>`. You should use a `React.Fragment` as the parent element:

```
render() {
   return (
     <>
        <h1>Drum Machine</h1>
        <div>
          //other stuff
        </div>
     </>
  );
}
```

There were also some syntax errors in the code, namely:

- not closing array in constructor
- no closing brace on `this.state` in constructor
- no braces around `map` expression in `render()`

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      drumPads: [
        {
          id: "Q",
          src: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3",
          beat: "Heater-1"
        },
        {
          id: "W",
          src: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-2.mp3",
          beat: "Heater-2"
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  handleClick(id, beat) {
    return () => {
      document.getElementById(id).play();
      this.setState({
        beatName: beat
      });
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h1>DrumMachine</h1>
        <div>
          {this.state.drumPads.map((button, i) =>
          <button key={i} onClick={this.handleClick(button.id, button.beat)}>
            <h1>{button.id}</h1>
            <audio id={button.id} src={button.src} />
          </button>
          )}
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Highly recommend telling people to use `Fragment` versus an unnecessary `div`!

Comment: BTW, here's a discussion on `div` vs `Fragment` from one of the core React people: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47761894/why-are-fragments-in-react-16-better-than-container-divs

Comment: Good call @Nick

Comment: I have edited the code and added Fragment, but still is not working.

Comment: Is the code as is in your question? If so, there are some syntax errors e.g. not closing out the drum pads array in constructor with `]`, or `this.state` closing brace

Comment: I've updated answer with a snippet with syntax errors fixed and it works as expected