# What are the advantages or disadvantages of putting our items in an empty div in React?

Tags: html, reactjs

When writing classic html we usually put our elements in a div and give this div a class name or id.
But in react, we place our elements in an empty div. We do not give both id and class name to this div.

What is the main reason for this? Can you explain?

My code sample is below.

**Empty div code example**

`

```
import classes from '../Input/Input.module.css';


const LoginPage = () => {
  return (

    <div>
      <div className={classes['login-page']} >
        <form>
          <h1 className={classes['login-header']} >Login</h1>
          <div className={classes.block}>
            <label>Email:</label>
            <input type="email"
              className={classes['classes-inputs']} />
          </div>
          <div className={classes.block}>
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="password"
              className={classes['classes-inputs']}
            />
          </div>
          <div className={classes.block}>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

  )
}


export default LoginPage;
```

`

**Non-empty div code sample**

`

```
import classes from '../Input/Input.module.css';


const LoginPage = () => {
  return (

    <div className={classes['login-page']} >
      <form>
        <h1 className={classes['login-header']} >Login</h1>
        <div className={classes.block}>
          <label>Email:</label>
          <input type="email"
            className={classes['classes-inputs']} />
        </div>
        <div className={classes.block}>
          <label>Password:</label>
          <input type="password"
            className={classes['classes-inputs']}
          />
        </div>
        <div className={classes.block}>
          <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

  )
}


export default LoginPage;
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases the wrapper div is “irrelevant” and is only added because React components require you to return only one element. This kind of behaviour results in useless markup and sometimes even invalid HTML to be rendered, which is bad.

For example we could have a component Table that renders an HTML table and inside that table the columns are rendered with another component called Columns. It would probably look something like this.

`

```
class Table extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <tr>
          <Columns />
        </tr>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
class Columns extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>World</td>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`

This would result in an invalid HTML to be rendered because the wrapper div from Columns component is rendered inside the .

`

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <div>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>World</td>
    </div>
  </tr>
</table>
```

`

React fragments let you group a list of children without adding extra nodes to the DOM because fragments are not rendered to the DOM. So basically we use React.Fragment where we would normally use a wrapper div.

We can make use of fragments with <React.Fragments> syntax. So we could write the Columns component as follows.

`

```
class Columns extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>World</td>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

`

Comment: You can also use <> ....</> instead of <React.Fragment>....</React.Fragment>

Comment: Yes, this is an easy use example, thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to actually.
The only limitation is that you must return a single element, so in the case you don't have a wrapper already you put an empty div around.
If you don't want to have an empty div you can use fragments `<></>` to wrap your elements

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is JSX parser I think.

JSX and React can return only one component so we can not do something like below

```
return (
  <ComponentA />
  <ComponentB />
  <ComponentC />
)
```

You must put a outermost wrapper for all of them and most of the time we use `<div>` tag

```
return (
  <div>
    <ComponentA />
    <ComponentB />
    <ComponentC />
  </div>
)
```

But you can use `React.Fragment` or its shortcut `<>` for opening tag and `</>` for closing tag.

```
return (
  <> // Can replace with <React.Fragment>
    <ComponentA />
    <ComponentB />
    <ComponentC />
  </> // Can replace with </React.Fragment>
)
```

There is some different between using `<div>` and `React.Fragment`. You can read it here [Why are Fragments in React 16 better than container divs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47761894/why-are-fragments-in-react-16-better-than-container-divs)

Answer (score 0):

No need to do it. If you consider JSX to be just functions of `React.createElement(...)` you can structure the tree you are building in JSX entirely with functions inside functions (hof).

Example:

```
return React.createElement('div',{
  children: React.createElement('div',{
    className: classes['login-page'],
    children: React.createElement(/* and so on */)
  })
})
```

You can immediately see that you can have started this "creation" of a tree at the second level of the divs. You can also see why the following is not possible similar to the other answers:

```
return (
  React.createElement('div',{})
  React.createElement('div',{})
  React.createElement('div',{})
)
```

And no, you don't need to return a single element. You could wrap that for valid javascript into:

```
return [
  React.createElement('div',{ key: 'some_id_1' }),
  React.createElement('div',{ key: 'some_id_2' }),
  React.createElement('div',{ key: 'some_id_3' })
]
```

That's why you should wrap everything into a fragment `<></>`, array or a single wrapper component/jsx-tag. Note the key attribute - React can do some optimisation magic with it.