# Can unnecessary React.Fragment be poor in performance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Recently, I found that our company's code performance is poor. As I reviewed code, there's so many codes like this:

```js
condition ? <SomeComponent /> : <></>
```

They use Fragment as replacement of null. Can this code occur performance problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's unlikely that the fragments are causing (if any) noticeable performance issues. As this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47762117/3778283) highlights, fragments don't actually create an extra DOM node.

With that said, the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#preventing-component-from-rendering) do suggest using `null` when you don't want a component to render at all, but again I don't think using them would be the root cause of any slowness in your app.

I'd look at potential unnecessary re-renders, especially in nested child components being re-rendered by parent components with state changes happening.

I'd also definitely a look at the [React Profiler](https://reactjs.org/docs/profiler.html) and use it to get a sense of what's causing any performance issues.